# Word2vec is not getting better with the number of epoch increasing

Tags: python, word2vec

Running this code give me back loss values that cycle not really decreasing. Could you explain me why ?

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts, get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec

class callback(CallbackAny2Vec):
    '''Callback to print loss after each epoch.'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.epoch = 0
        self.previous_loss = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        loss = model.get_latest_training_loss()
        print('Loss after epoch {}: {}'.format(self.epoch, loss-self.previous_loss))
        self.epoch += 1
        self.previous_loss = loss

model = Word2Vec(datapath('lee_background.cor'),epochs=10000,
                 compute_loss=True, callbacks=[callback()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Loss can't decrease forever, unless:

- the model can perfectly memorize the training set; *and*
- every input – in the case of word2vec, context skip-gram or CBOW word(s) – should always generate the exact same outputs

The latter definitely isn't the case in natural-language: neither one skip-gram word `X`, nor a window of CBOW words `X1, X2, ... Xn`, will *always* exactly predict a target word. Hence, there will always be loss-against-training-examples.

All that you're doing with training (stochastic-gradient-descent optimization) is driving loss to the smallest that's practical given the mechanism/size of the chosen model.

At some point, at a still non-zero loss, changing the model to be better on some training-examples necessarily worsens it on others.

At this point, often called 'convergence', further training can only cause measured loss to jitter up-and-down around some range-of-approximately-best-value. Which seems to be what you're describing.

Related: a model with lower loss is better at the *training* task – mechanistically predicting words among the texts of the training set. But it won't necessarily be better at all the other downstream things you want to use word-vectors for.

At a certain point, being superficially better at the training-set – memorizing every detail, even the idiosyncratic non-generalizable things – can make things *worse* for other out-of-training-set tasks. That's 'overfitting'.

Especially with small training-sets, you can see this for yourself by expanding the `vector_size`. Some size will do best for specific other tasks – creating word-vectors that reflect what you want about the word's relationships – but an ever-larger size will do worse.

(It'll also, at some point, make the model larger than the training-data – an imbalance that practically ensures overfitting, because all 'learning' typically needs to have some aspect of *compression*: boiling a smaller number of useful compact lessons from a larger amount of suggestive/noisy data.)

That's why assessing model fitness for your project requires evaluations other than just looking-at-loss. Ideally these evaluations are even project-specific, though often more generic ones – like say the analogy-solving often applied to word2vec models – may point in the roughly right direction to match human-salient word senses. Still: on any project-specific goal, like classification or info-retrieval, the word-vectors 'best' at analogy-solving might not be best for the project's purposes.